# Plotting two plots in one graph after matching values in a column

Tags: python-3.x, csv, matplotlib

I have a test.csv file which looks like

```
Company   Year   Actual   Predicted
A         2010    500       700
A         2011    600       650
A         2012    700       690
B         2010    800       590
B         2011    670       800
B         2012    570       600
```

I want to plot curves company wise.

Which means I will have two curves for this dataset; one for company A and another for company B. And I want the curves to look like this

[image]

I am new to python so I need help.

I tried this code

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  csv
Year=[]
Prediction=[]
Actual=[]

with open('C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\New Beginnings\\financial\\test1.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots =csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for column in plots:
        Year.append(int(column[1]))
        Prediction.append(int(column[3]))
        Actual.append(int(column[2]))

plt.plot(Year,Prediction,Actual ,label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Actual')

plt.title('Share Market Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But there are a few problems with this code.

First is I get this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Predicted'`

And second is I didn't add any code to seperate company wise plotting.

Can someone please edit the following code? Thanks for help.

Comment: You tagged excel, those would plot fine in an excel chart.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited the question. @SolarMike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## int conversion

You can execute

```
    next(csvfile)
```

just before assigning `plots`, to skip the initial line of column headers.
Converting a textual header to an `int` won't work, as you saw.

## company-wise plotting

Define a function:

```
def plot_actual_and_predicted(company, filename):
```

Put most of your code within that function.
Now insert a test so your loop looks like this:

```
    for column in plots:
        if column[0] == company:
            Year.append(int(column[1]))
            Prediction.append(int(column[3]))
            Actual.append(int(column[2]))
```

Call the function twice to obtain a pair of plots:

```
plot_actual_and_predicted('A', filename)
plot_actual_and_predicted('B', filename)
```

Each call will pull out just a company-specific slice of the data,
similar to doing `$ egrep '^A,' *.csv`, or grepping out lines starting with `B`.